# Remove element from array that exist in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I remove an element from an array that exist in mysql table

```
 $word = array('من','الى','على','عن','في','-','@','#','$','(',')','[',']','و');// create an array
 $explode = explode(" ",$title);
 $search = array_diff($explode,$word);//delete element if exist in the array word
 $implode = implode(",",$search);//implode the array search

 $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select db_key from tbl_keyword where db_key IN ('$implode')")
        or die(mysqli_error($conn));// select from the table where column in $implode
 $found = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
     $found[] = $row['db_key'];
 }
 $not_found = array_diff($search, $found); print_r($not_found)."<br/>";
 $imp = implode(",",$not_found);
 $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into tbl_keyword(db_key,db_tid) 
                                values ('$imp','$last_id')")
         or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

My Problem is in this part of code where I want to remove the element from the array that exist in the table i don't want to have a duplicate word in the table

```
$found = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $found[] = $row['db_key'];
}
$not_found = array_diff($search, $found);print_r($not_found)."<br/>";
$imp = implode(",",$not_found);
$insert = mysqli_query($conn,"insert into tbl_keyword(db_key,db_tid) 
                              values ('$imp','$last_id')")
          or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

When I print the `$not_found` I have an empty array

How Can I solve this problem 
Remove element from array that exist in mysql database
[image]

Comment: One thing you can do is to add the unique constraint for your column in the database table.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte in the database db_key is stored like that name,aaa,bbb with a cama the unique key will work with that? what i want if name is repeated another time will be remove and the other word will be insert

Comment: first print separate array before array_diff
print_r($search);
print_r($found):
if print ok then check next

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam it give me that Array ( ) and also i print that echo mysqli_num_rows($query); and i have 0

Comment: And your table actually has only two columns (one id and a comma separated string)?

Comment: just array without data? so which array just print empty array ?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte please check above how the data is in the database

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam this from the query

Comment: so found data not print data? check your first 4 line that is it ok?

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam the $import contain value

Comment: ok then echo this 
echo select db_key from tbl_keyword where db_key IN ('$implode');
then run this in phpmyadmin then check

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam when i test in phpmyadmin i have empty rows no result

Comment: as a result found array empty then if search array have data then not_found will be same search array

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam How to solve it ?!

Comment: Question 1. you want to get data from database ?
Question 2. find array diff from search and found array?

Comment: i want get data from database and found array diff from search and found array

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a pretty solution, but your non-pretty, non-1NF table structure demands it.  Swap out `IN` for `FIND_IN_SET`.

```
SELECT `db_key` FROM `tbl_keyword` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`db_key`,'$implode')
```